# Webpack require.context does not work with Path.resolve

Tags: javascript, webpack

**webpack.config.js**

```
"use strict";
const Path = require("path");
const resolvePath = (...paths) => Path.resolve(__dirname, ...paths);

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    data: "./src/data/index.ts" // resolvePath("src", "data", "index.ts") does not work
  }
  /** more **/
}
```

**index.ts**

```
const req = require.context("./yaml", true, /\.ya?ml$/i);
req.keys().forEach((key: any) => req(key));
```

Using `"./src/data/index.ts"` or `resolvePath("src", "data", "index.ts")` compile the code. But only `"./src/data/index.ts"` includes the YAML files. YAML files are located at `./src/data/yaml`.

How does `Path.resolve` affect `require.context`? If I want to use `Path.resolve`, how should I write the correct `require.context`?

Comment: Is your regex in  "require.context("./yaml",true,/\.ya?ml$/i) " line is correct??

Comment: @PALLAMOLLA SAI Yes. As I have said it works with `./src/data/index.ts`